# PostgreSQL Exercise: GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I met a problem when doing PostgreSQL Exercises-Classify facilities by value. 
Here is the question link: https://pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/classify.html

I tried:

```
select name,
  (case when rank <= max(rank)/3 then 'high'
        when rank > max(rank)/3 and rank <= max(rank)*2/3 then 'average'
        else 'low' end) as revenue 
from
 (select name, rank() over (order by sum(
         case when boo.memid=0 then slots*guestcost
              when boo.memid!=0 then slots*membercost end) desc) as rank
  from cd.bookings boo join cd.facilities fac on boo.facid=fac.facid
  group by name) subq
```

I also tried:

```
with subq as 
 (select name, rank() over (order by sum(
         case when boo.memid=0 then slots*guestcost
              when boo.memid!=0 then slots*membercost end) desc) as rank
  from cd.bookings boo join cd.facilities fac on boo.facid=fac.facid
  group by name)
select name,
   (case when rank <= max(rank)/3 then 'high'
         when rank > max(rank)/3 and rank <= max(rank)*2/3 then 'average'
         else 'low' end) as revenue from subq
```

Both appear error: column "sub.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I'm very confused and don't know what't wrong in my code. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must group the result table by **name** and **rank**.

Simply append this to your statement and it will run without an error:

```sql
group by name, rank
```